# Change WiFi Roaming Agressiveness - Xperia 1 IV

Tags: wi-fi, sony-xperia

I've just got an Xperia 1 IV and I've noticed that it's not roaming between the access points in my house, which is an absolute nightmare.

I've looked, and I can't seem to find this setting anywhere.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you checked if your Wifi routers and the phone support any of the roaming related Wifi improvements (802.11k 802.11r 802.11v). As far as I know without those standards roaming isn't working very well.

Comment: I would assume so since the phone is new and no other device on my network struggles with this.

Comment: [Caveat: I have zero knowledge about network engineering.] My Xperia 10 III wouldn't connect to our work wifi, but it would connect to the same network elsewhere and maintain the connection if I walked back to my office. This has now been resolved, and I was told the problem was that our access point used 802.11r (fast transition). From what I read online, this has to be supported by your device driver. I agree that it's strange that this wouldn't be the case for new Xperia models, but maybe they are using old parts?